# Why my i phone say Cannot Determine Location?

Tags: ios, xcode, settings, mkmapview, gprs

I am trying to implement ios mapView related application,Before 3 hour my application working fine and getting current location and every things. Now i didn't get Current location .
So i open Maps(Iphone Application) ,the same problems is coming some other application. So i check wifi Connection and reset network.
 Unfortunately i am getting  an alert message `**Cannot Determine Location**`

How can fix this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go outside and try again. The wifi information will help if your wifi router's MAC address is in the Skyhook database, but if it isn't then it won't be doing you any good. Go outside and maybe your iPhone will be able to hear the satellites needed to determine a location.